# Get name of all classes who dont have 'X' class

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

Having html list as ,

```
<ul id="test">
    <li class="A"></li>
    <li class="B"></li>
    <li class="C"></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="E"></li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="F"></li>
<ul>
```

Want to get all class names except empty class name.
How can i get it using jquery ?
Expected result like `A B C E F`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()` and `.get()` to collect those class names in an array and display it according to your requirement.

Try,

```
$('#test li').map(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('empty')){
     return $(this).attr('class');
  } 
}).get().join('');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/soosmca/bPSbk/)

or

```
$("#test li:not(.empty)").map(function(){ 
  return $(this).attr('class');
}).get().join('');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#test').find('*:not(".empty")')
```

If you want to target only `li` element then:

```
$('#test').find('li:not(".empty")')
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q37SV/)

Comment: He wants the class names, not just elements.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
$("#test li:not(.empty)")
```

Code:

```
$("#test li:not(.empty)").each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr('class') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function()
  {
      $("li:not(.empty)").each(function(){
          alert($(this).attr("Class"));
      });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DnSNJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var classes = {};
$('#test li:not(.empty)').each(function(){
    //this work only if the target element has one class, if there are multiple classes in an element this has to be redesigned
    classes[this.className] = true;
})
var array = $.map(classes, function(value, key){
    return key;
});

console.log(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdgf6/)

Comment: I am very curious to ask, why are you iterating twice in this context. Thanks.

Comment: just to make sure the class values are unique... if there are 2 elements with same class

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test li:not(.empty)").each(function()
{
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```